# Passing undifined to Handlebars.compile

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I just started with Handlebars.js and running into a small problem

I'm using version 1.0.0 width data I get from JSON via jQuery. Everything works fine, my data gets pulled through to the template and the data gets displayed like expected, however I keep getting this error.

```
Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
```

When I log source in the console I get this, I know it's not a string but this is what this tutorial explains http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/05/javascript-templating-handlebars-tutorial/. Am I wrong?

```
{{#sets}}
<li class="products">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <img src="{{img}}">
</li>
{{/sets}}
```

Here is the rest of it

HTML

```
<div id="sets-template-inner" class="show-for'small">
        <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
            <div class="preloader"></div>
            <ul data-orbit> 
                <script id="full-sets-template-mobile" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                        {{#sets}}
                            <li class="products">
                                <h1>{{title}}</h1>
                                <img src="{{img}}">
                            </li>
                        {{/sets}}
                </script>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
function getProductsSets() {
  $.getJSON('products/products.json', {
      format: "json"
    }).done(function(json) {
      $.each(json.sets, function() {
        var source = $('#full-sets-template-mobile').html();
        console.log(source)
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var data = template(json);
        var html = $('#sets-template-inner').html(data);
      });
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('failed');
    });
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "sets":
    [
            {
                    "title": "raw bones",
                    "img": "img/sets/set1.jpg",
                    "desc": "Raw pine table with 2 chairs and a bench.",
                    "base": 1200,
                    "seating":
                    [
                            {
                                    "price": 0,
                                    "name": "4 seater"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price": 400,
                                    "name": "6 seater"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price": 800,
                                    "name": "8 seater"
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "title": "sky blue",
                    "img": "img/sets/set1.jpg",
                    "desc": "Raw pine table with 2 chairs and a bench",
                    "base": 1300,
                    "seating":
                    [
                            {
                                    "price": 0,
                                    "name": "4 seater"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price": 500,
                                    "name": "6 seater"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price": 800,
                                    "name": "8 seater"
                            }
                    ]   
            }
    ]
```

}

Hope I have enough info here and thanks for any help.

Comment: You're looping over `$.each(json.sets,` but then inside the loop you consume the entire `json` variable every time. It seems you really don't need the `$.each` here.

Answer (score 0):

just do away with the {{#sets}}   {{/sets}} I think.  You're jquery is already breaking the object down to each set. so all you need is

```
<script id="full-sets-template-mobile" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li class="products">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <img src="{{img}}">
    </li>
</script>
```

in your template

Comment: How will this effect the `Handlebars.compile(undefined)` problem?

Comment: everything is encapsulated by the #sets, if handlebars can't see the sets it can't compile the rest of the stuff

Comment: But Handlebars will never see that because it Handlebars never sees the template text at all. `source` is `undefined` when the `Handlebars.compile(source)` call is made, that's what the error message is saying. Possible problems with the template itself come later.

Comment: You'll also notice that the template function is being called with the full `json`, not the slices that `$.each(json.sets, ...)` will be producing.

Comment: as to the comment from mu is too short farther above.  He is right, you could use $('#data-orbit).append(html); though

Comment: yeah mu you're right. In that case he needs to use something like {{#each sets}} instead of just {{#sets}}

Comment: but there could a referencing issue with it being an array of objects

Comment: The code never gets past `Handlebars.compile(source)` though, the `template(json)` call should be fine but there shouldn't be a `$.each` involved at all as the template has its own loop.

Comment: The template(json) call could be fine if the template was set up correctly.  Then yes he wouldn't need the $.each loop.  He would need to loop through with {{#each sets}}. 

As it stands the error is complex(in the fact that it takes place in multiple areas) and there are multiple ways to fix it.

He could change the $.each(json.sets, function()    to $.each(json.sets, function( index, set){ ... template(set) });

Comment: What @muistooshort is saying is that the `var source = $('#full-sets-template-mobile').html();` is setting source to `undefined` meaning it is not getting the template at all (as if it were not loaded in the DOM yet, or it was written wrong). Any debugging past that comes *after* this one is figured out.